# S3 bucket back-up NOT on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking for a service to back-up s3 buckets that isn't hosted on Amazon so that there is complete separation but there doesn't seem to be much.

It's for periodic (daily) back-up of < 500GB

Maybe just scripting to Azure or google cloud?

Or any suggestions for a service in the EU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any services, but it's not difficult to roll your own.

**Option One**

Get a VPS, install the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), and run a command the [aws s3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) such as something like this (I don't think this is quite right but I'm not on the right machine to look up the syntax)

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucketname/ file://folder/
```

That isn't a backup - that's a copy. You would then run backup software to create an incremental backup so you can restore files. I like [Restic](https://restic.net/).

**Option Two**

If you have a suitable VM you could run backup software on your instance to backup anywhere you like. Again, I like Restic, which can back up to [many locations](https://restic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/030_preparing_a_new_repo.html) such as sFtp, REST server, B2, etc. Restic doesn't compress, but it does de-duplicate.

The restic docs are good. You just set up your backup location, do a "restic init", then "restic backup". You should do the prune process occasionally, which is I think a "forget" then a "prune" command. You can likely get it all done in a couple of hours, then set it up on a cron job.

**Option Three**

You could use something like [S3FS](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount your S3 bucket then use the dropbox CLI to sync up to Dropbox. Dropbox has some version history.